# parse int to date (tmap ) Talend PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, parsing, etl, talend

My job Talend is about mapping between a csv file and a postregresql table.
I need to insert a column date which can be with normal format yyyyMMdd or(0/99999999) in the csv file. So if the date is equal to 0 or 99999999 it's will be mapping as a null variable in the database, else the  data must be loaded as a date type timestamp yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.

In the csv file I declared the date as an int, so I must parse int to a datetime in the tmap and loaded the 0/99999999 as a null variable.
Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand the problem correctly, its solution is as follows:
[image]

// correspondent expression to convert string with special "0/99999999" values is:
(row1.dateAsString.equals("0")||row1.dateAsString.equals("99999999"))?null:routines.TalendDate.parseDate("yyyyMMdd", row1.dateAsString)